# Xubuntu live usb fail to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu, live-usb

I want to make my laptop (with legacy bios) be able to dual boot ubuntu and windows 10, so I make a bootable usb following the official guide with rufus. However I can never go past the boot screen. I tried to find past solution to this problem, but I can't seem to find any. I always stuck on boot, never be able to go past it even with using nomodeset and different ubuntu flavors. I always stuck on this line

`systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'`

even when I waited for 30 minutes it never got to the desktop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: not yet, I'm gonna try switching boot media to dvd and see how it goes

Comment: Are you installing both Windows 10 and Xubuntu in Legacy mode? GRUB does not like Windows and Linux booting in different modes. A USB made using Rufus with GPT Partition Scheme will not boot or install in Legacy mode.

Comment: I make the usb using MBR partition, so its supposed to not be a problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your laptop can't handle the reading of your usb-stick (AHCI Problem). Check your bios, if you can change anything concerning the "boot from USB", else try another stick.

Also make sure, that your iso checksum is correct - here is [how to do it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto)

Answer (score 0):

### Select 'dd-mode' in Rufus and try again

**dd-mode** means that Rufus will **clone** from the iso file to the USB drive (instead of the more complicated creation of partition table, file system, bootloader and extraction of the content from the iso file to the file system in the USB drive.

Cloning means that every byte of the iso file is copied as it is to the target drive, and it is a robust process, very likely to succeed, and cloning makes all Ubuntu family iso files bootable both in UEFI mode and legacy mode (alias CSM alias BIOS mode).